# Configuring ha-proxy for "war" file in jetty

Tags: jetty, high-availability, haproxy

I am new to Ha-proxy and stuck in a situation.

I have configured ha-proxy for two server 10.x.y.10 and 10.x.y.20. These two run jetty.

Everything is working fine if one of the jetty is down. The request goes to second server and everything happens as expected.

PROBLEM : Suppose both jetty are running and if i remove "war" file from one jetty , the request does not goes to second server. It just gives error "Error 404 Not Found"

I know i have configured ha-proxy for jetty not for the war files but is there any way to redirect request if the war file is missing  or the requested situation is not even possible.

Please point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

This is my haproxy configuration.

## HA PROXY CONFIGURATION

```
defaults
mode                    http
log                     global
option                  httplog
option              logasap
option                  dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
option                  redispatch
retries                 3
timeout http-request    10s
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         10s
timeout client          1m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check           10s
maxconn                 3000



 frontend vs_http_80
    bind *:9090
    default_backend pool_http_80

 backend pool_http_80
    #balance options
    balance roundrobin

    #http options
    mode http
    option httpchk OPTIONS /
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close

    #monitoring service endpoints with healthchecks
    server pool_member1 10.x.y.10:8080 // x and y are dummy variables
    server pool_member2 10.x.y.20:8080

 frontend vs_stats :8081
    mode http
    default_backend stats_backend

 backend stats_backend
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Stats\ Page
    stats auth serveruser:password
    stats admin if TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution. In case anybody comes across the same issue , please find the solution below.

The following link solved my problem

http://tecadmin.net/haproxy-acl-for-load-balancing-on-url-request/

Basically the following line entry in the frontend configuration did the trick.

```
acl is_blog url_beg  /blog
use_backend tecadmin_blog if is_blog
default_backend tecadmin_website
```

ACL = Access Control list -> ACLs are used to test some condition and perform an action

If the precondition is satisfied then it redirects to backend server.
We can use mulitple acls and direct to muliple backend through same front end.

Next in the backend server configuration we need to add "check" in the end which monitures its health condition.

```
backend tecadmin_website
mode http
balance roundrobin  # Load Balancing algorithm
option httpchk
option forwardfor
server WEB1 192.168.1.103:80 check
server WEB2 192.168.1.105:80 check
```

Here's the complete configuration for my problem.

```
defaults
 mode                    http
 log                     global
 option                  httplog
 option              logasap
  option                  dontlognull
 option http-server-close
 option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
 option                  redispatch
 retries                 3
 timeout http-request    10s
 timeout queue           1m
  timeout connect         10s
  timeout client          1m
 timeout server          1m
 timeout http-keep-alive 10s
 timeout check           10s
  maxconn                 3000



frontend vs_http_80
bind *:9090

acl x1_app path_dir x1
acl x2_app path_dir x2

acl x1_avail nbsrv(backend_x1) ge 1
acl x2_avail nbsrv(backend_x2) ge 1

use_backend backend_x1 if x1_app1 x1_avail
use_backend backend_x2 if x2_app x2_avail


 backend backend_x1
    #balance options
    balance roundrobin

    #http options
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /x1
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close

    #monitoring service endpoints with healthchecks
    server pool_member1 10.x.y.143:8080/x1 check
    server pool_member2 10.x.y.141:8080/x2 check


 backend backend_x2
    #balance options
    balance roundrobin

    #http options
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /x2
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close

    #monitoring service endpoints with healthchecks
    server pool_member1 10.x.y.143:8080/x2 check
    server pool_member2 10.x.y6.141:8080/x2 check




frontend vs_stats :8081
mode http
default_backend stats_backend

 backend stats_backend
mode http
stats enable
stats uri /stats
stats realm Stats\ Page
stats auth serveruser:password
stats admin if TRUE
```